# How to control the order of the combination of enqueued styles and scripts - site speed issue

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, performance

We know, using `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` all the scripts and styles are enqueued using `wp_enqueue_styles` and `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. What we do is to enqueue our stylesheets and scripts using `functions.php`. And similarly WordPress plugins also enqueue their stylesheets and scripts using the same method.

So, in the end there are many enqueued styles and scripts in header or footer. What Google PageSpeed recommends is:

> [**Optimize the order of styles and scripts**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#PutStylesBeforeScripts) - Google PageSpeed

We know, `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` offer a `$deps` parameter, where we can define the depth or priority of the script or stylesheet. But that affects only within scripts and styles, not in both. So, with a combined load of scripts and stylesheets from the theme, and/or child theme, and/or plugins, and/or third party API etc. how can we let the WordPress to enqueue them all in a way so that site speed improves with a sound website's quality?
Or, are they bulletproof to echo styles first, than scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer this as best as possible given that there is no bulletproof method.

It's up to the developer to really plan out how the DOM is painted, WordPress cannot guess as to what a theme/plugin/user is going to be doing, it can simply provide some guidance and basic tools. The problem of course is when many plugins are added to a site, you can have a mess on your hands. This is what separates a well crafted site structure from one hastily clicked into place.

The `$deps` does not really define priority, it only provides dependency context. You can actually define priority in the action hook using the `$priority` parameter. There is nothing wrong with using multiple `wp_enqueue_scripts` with different `$priority` settings.

Some pointers.

- Come up with a load structure for your css/js, write it
  down, analyze it using Developer Tools, Firebug, etc, to inspect how the page
  is painted.
- Use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action for `wp_enqueue_style`
- Use `$priority`  and `$in_footer` for your actions
- Load javascript asynchronously if possible, and load as little javascript as needed.
- Cache everything

Example of inspecting frame loading in developer tools, mousing over these details provides more call stack info.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice answer Wyck. I love Chrome's Dev. Tools, and would love to be on the course you suggested. Thank you.